# swagger-codegen-maven-plugin how can I check which version of OAS is supported

Tags: swagger-codegen

I feel a bit stupid, trying to find which exactly version of OAS is supported by my plugin:

```
    <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.52</version>
```

I looked in the docs of both plugin and swagger-codegen, tried to checked dependencies in maven (but got lost), checked release notes and I know OAS 3.1 was already announced, tried to find a config option with that value, but I did not get the definite answer. Is there a simple way of checking this basic information?

Update: I checked that OAS 3.1 is still not supported :-(, by trying to use 3.1 spec. But that is not a  way I want to do that.